# Android: Using spinner to update an RealmObject

Tags: android, realm

I have two RealmObjects, something like,

```
public class Dog extends RealmObject {
    @Required
    private String name;
    private int age;
    }
public class Person extends RealmObject {
    @Required
    private String name;
    private Dog dog; // A person has only one dog (a relationship)
    }
```

In one of the activities, I want to let the user select the dog for the given person.

I thought I will use a spinner.

I also got a sample code from Realm-Examples, that did similar stuff for the ListView.

```
public class DogListAdapter extends RealmBaseAdapter<Dog> implements SpinnerAdapter
```

So far everything works fine. The spinner list automatically updates to reflect changes in the realm.

But, when I have to first display the GUI, I want to set the selected item to the current Person.dog.name.

What is the best way to do this?

I am doing something like this in onResume():

```
dogNameSpinner.setSelection(RealmUtils.resultIndexOf(dogsResult, person.getDog()));
```

where, the `RealmUtils.resultIndexOf` is a small utility function:

```
public static int resultIndexOf(RealmResults results, RealmObject obj) {
    for(int i=0; i < results.size(); i++ ) {
        if(results.get(i) == obj) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This does not work. I suspect may be because the realm.changeListeners get called and the spinner resets to the first item whenever items are updated.. ??

I suppose there could be a better way to do this as it should be a common model-view use case.

Comment: I think it happens to the user selection as well, not only the first default selection. My guess is your selected-index needs to be changed when the data changes. So instead of storing a index, you'd better store a selected-dog, and compute the index and call `dogNameSpinner.setSelection` in the change listener.

Comment: Thanks for your time and comment. I found the problem to be in computing the index. I think we can not use == operator. One thing is that it had to be cast to Dog class. Even after that, it did not work. I am not sure why. It appears `Person.dog` will not pass `==` operator on any of the `results.get(i)`. I was assuming, within a single realm instance, all Java RealmObjects of the same underlying model point to the same address. It does not seem to be true.
So, I had to replace `results.get(i) == obj` with `results.get(i).getName().equals(obj.getName())`

Comment: Is there any way to test if two RealmObjects indeed point to the same object ?

Comment: Yes, use `RealmObject.equals()`. You have to make sure they are both `RealmObject` managed by Realm, not standalone object which is created by `new RealmXXXObject()`.